# Applying CSS styling TOP correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of new to css styling, so I went by something that I couldn't really express how to solve, I hope that it is clear in the image attached, I just want to put this label beside the top of this textarea, could any one please help in this

[image]

Comment: Label and then under the label text area, right?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/zcpteade/

Comment: or this one https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/zcpteade/1/

Comment: yes exactly @Leothelion the first one

Comment: @Leothelion so do you have any idea ?

Comment: that is an live example. See i have used vertical-align:top so use that in your case and it will work. For more detail read my answer.

Comment: Use `CSS` `vartical-align` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you are asking is called vertical-align and in your case i have used `vertical-align:top`

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/zcpteade/)

The vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment of an element. You can read more about vertical-align [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
     <label>Employee Comments</label>
     <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 label{vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Leo

Comment: My pleasure to help you :)